# javascript function can not identify the argument from asp.net pageload

Tags: asp.net

I have a **function** like

```
                $(function donutchartcreation(numbers) { 

                     alert(numbers[1]); 

                    }
```

I tried to call this function from asp.net codebehind pageload as

```
         int[] numbers = { 27, 20, 30 };
         string serializedNumbers = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(numbers);
         System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "donutchartcreation", "donutchartcreation( " + serializedNumbers + ");", true);
```

Here number[1] can not be identified.. Can you plz help me to find the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove jQuery (i.e $) wrapper. Change

```
    $(function donutchartcreation(numbers) { 

          alert(numbers[1]); 

     }
```

to:

```
    function donutchartcreation(numbers) {

        alert(numbers[1]);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**you can try as below:**

but before that make your javascript function like

**javascript**

```
function donutchartcreation(numbers) { 

          alert(numbers[1]); 

     }
```

**code behind**

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "donutchartcreation", javascript:donutchartcreation('"+ serializedNumbers +"')", true);
```

i hope it will help you.